# ubuntu 20.04 not accept to shut down

Tags: shutdown

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 and after that my laptop refuses to shutdown via `power off` command. It reboots not shutdown. My laptop is **HP zbook 15 g2**. I tried many fix tools via **grub** file but problem still persists. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo shutdown -h now`, or `sudo poweroff`?

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Is `HP Zbook G2` your complete/correct make/model #? 15" or 17"?

Comment: M70 Ver. 01.20 my laptop is HP Zbook 15 G2